# how to implement jmeter request post from a cURL command

Tags: curl, header, request, jmeter, saml

I need to implement a jmeter script from this cURL command:

```
curl -X POST -u "Oezvjl4Ffju8Y0sLTXwfTuUHyHMa:vwe7v7AaontzlOfiefCRjrYWpUwa"
-H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"
-d "grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:saml2-bearer&assertion=PD94bWwgd...."
-k https://$host/oauth2/token
```

The -u flag should specify the `<Client Id>:<Client Secret>` value. The assertion parameter should specify the base64url encoded SAML2.0 assertion.

How do I value the parameter -u and -d in jmeter request?
I try using HTTP Header Manager as below:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8
client_id: Oezvjl4Ffju8Y0sLTXwfTuUHyHMa
code: vwe7v7AaontzlOfiefCRjrYWpUwa
```

and I put `grant_type=...` in the body data of http post request.. but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

**Easier way:** - just record the call.

1. Launch [JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)
2. In shell:

   - `export http_proxy=http://localhost:8080/`
   - `curl .......`

Captured request will be under [Recording Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Recording_Controller).

**Harder way:** - if you want complete control

JMeter equivalent will look as follows:

- Thread Group

  - [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request)

    - [HTTP Header Manager](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager)

*HTTP Request Configuration:*

- Server Name or IP: `$host`
- Protocol: `https`
- Method: `POST`
- Content encoding: `UTF-8`
- Path: `/oauth2/token`
- Body data: `grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:saml2-bearer&assertion=PD94bWwgd....`

*HTTP Header Manager Configuration:*

- Name: `Authorization`
- Value: `Basic T2V6dmpsNEZmanU4WTBzTFRYd2ZUdVVIeUhNYTp2d2U3djdBYW9udHpsT2ZpZWZDUmpyWVdwVXdh`

Comment: i try the harder way but.. {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client Authentication failed."}