# Auto create jmeter script from existed curl command

Tags: curl, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Just wanna the quickest way to create a jmeter script from existed curl command, any workable approaches ?

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to implement jmeter request post from a cURL command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26016684/how-to-implement-jmeter-request-post-from-a-curl-command)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to record your curl call with [JMeter's Proxy Server](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

1. Open JMeter GUI
2. From main menu: File -> Templates -> Recording -> Create
3. Expand "Workbench"
4. Click "Start" under the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder
5. Open terminal
6. Execute your curl command like:

   ```
   curl -x http://localhost:8888 .......
   ```

References:

- [JMeter Proxy Step by Step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf)
- [How to Save ‘Loads’ of Time Using JMeter's Template Feature](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature)
- [curl command manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/curl)